# Defining Kubernetes Replica Set/Deployment and services in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline using Kubernetes and Jenkins. Now I am exploring about the CI part using Jenkins file, SVN repository with Docker Hub. After pushing the Docker image into registry docker hub , I need to deploy this into a Kubernetes cluster having 3 cluster master and 15 worker machine/node.

When I am reading deployment into Kubernetes cluster I have several doubts:

Every deployment definition within the Jenkins is writes using the shell script. If I need to create my Deployment and Services for those deployments, How I can define in Jenkins?  Where I can create the YAML/YML files for ReplicaSet, Deployment and Services? Do I need to use shell scripting for this? Or in any other method?

Comment: Usually you would use Jenkins to pull down the source. Your codebase would then contain the appropriate configuration yaml for deployment. Then in the Build section under Execute Shell you can add the appropriate `kubectl` commands that would deploy your cluster and scale it up accordingly.

Comment: OK I understood that. But there we only mentioning the updation of that deployment. How the image pulling is happening there ? It will automatically pulling ? Or Do we need to add manually anything in that shell portion of Jenkins? I did not understood its work flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Kubernetes Helm](https://helm.sh/) to define what you want to spin up, in parameterisable modules called Helm charts. Many charts are available for common software like nginx and postgresql. This allows an "infrastructure as code" way of working - declaratively specifying what you want, instead of using a script to manually get the cluster into the desired state from whatever state it is currently in, just rely on Helm to do that for you! This is a good use case for Helm.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Currently I searched based on shell script only. This is new information for me. Let me check this Helm that you suggested. But can you give the idea of image pulling from docker hub while making deployment? .How I can pull the image and how I can define deployment/replicaset in jenkins ? That is my confusion.

Comment: Kubernetes pulls the image for you. There is no need for a separate step for that.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on an open source project called [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) which is a proposed sub project of the Jenkins foundation aimed at automating CI/CD on Kubernetes using Jenkins pipelines and GitOps for promotion across environments.

If you want to see how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using helm for package management, GitOps for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests you might wanna check out [my recent talk on Jenkins X at DevOxx UK](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/devoxx-uk-2018/) where I do a live demo of this on GKE. Though Jenkins X works on [AWS, AKS and GKE and other kubernetes clusters too](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/).

Comment: Can you add the link again please?